# I want the value for key open_now in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
Opening :- (
"Not Available",
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
"Not Available",
    {
    "open_now" = 1;
    "weekday_text" =         (
    );
},
"Not Available"
```

)

This is an output of my NSArray. It contains some strings as Not Available and it contains some NSDictionary starting with { "open_now" = 1; "weekday_text" = ( ); } .I wanted the value of only open_now. I don't know how to get value of open_now in my new NSArray. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Reformat the post, insert 8 spaces before the text to indent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the NSArray -valueForKey: method.

```
NSArray *extracted = [sourceArray valueForKey:@"a key"];
```

Comment: Please let us know ur code sample , might help me to understand where is the issue .

Answer (score 0):

You can use **valueForKeyPath** method of **NSArray** to get value of particular key.

```
NSArray *aryValue = [YOUR_ARRAY valueForKeyPath:@"open_now"];
```

Comment: Its not working. In my array there is some string and some NSDictionary randomly stored. so i wanted value for  key "open_now" only. it is giving exception :-                                                                                    
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x10ba54d20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key open_now.'